# Estimating the number of apples in an apple tree using MCMC

Tags: bayesian, estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I'm trying to estimate the number of apples in an apple tree by
repeatedly kicking the tree and counting how many apples fall down.
This process, I believe, is called *removal sampling*.

The only assumption I'm making is that there is a constant probability
$p$ that an apple falls down when I kick the tree.

Given that, e.g., `[100, 10, 1, 0]` apples fall down, I'm prone to
believe that $p \sim 0.9$ and that $N$, the total number of apples, is
111.

I'm trying to estimate $N$ using MCMC, but I seem to struggle to get it
right.

First, I've picked $N$ to be a uniform discrete prior in $[0, 1000]$ and $p$ is chosen to be a flat uniform over $[0, 1]$.

But, suppose that I remove, e.g., `[19, 17, 13, 1, 1]`, I used

$$
\begin{align}
N   &= \text{DiscreteUniform}(0, 1000)\\
p   &= \text{Uniform}(0, 1)\\
q_1 &= \text{Binomial}(N, p, \text{observed}=19)\\
q_2 &= \text{Binomial}(N - q_1, p, \text{observed}=17)\\
q_3 &= \text{Binomial}(N - (q_1 + q_2), p, \text{observed}=13)\\
q_4 &= \text{Binomial}(N - (\sum_j^{3} q_j), p, \text{observed}=1)\\
q_5 &= \text{Binomial}(N - (\sum_j^{4} q_j), p, \text{observed}=1)
\end{align}
$$

With this model, I end up with an estimate on $N \sim 54.5$.  A different model I tried consistently get $N \leq 53$.

**My question is the following:**

Are my $q_i$ correctly modeled, or are they possibly the reason my model is over-estimating?

Do you see any obvious mistakes?

---

[image: Simulating the aforementioned removal example]

Comment: I don't know how this affects the posterior but N should be discrete for the binomial and your prior for N is continuous?

Comment: Yes, _N_ should be discrete, and I just used TruncatedNormal because I didn't know what else to use.  This is literally all I know of my apple trees: _N_ have been estimated previously to `[6, 38, 53, 112, 140, 145, 264]`.

Comment: When I tried with a flat discrete prior, it over-estimated much more, especially if the upper bound was too high (e.g. 1000).

Comment: How can you tell that it over-estimates? The data puts a lower bound on N of 51.

Comment: I'd probably be suspicious of another model that put all its mass on 51, 52, or 53...

Comment: I believe it over-estimates because there are two industry standard ways of estimating, and they both give lower numbers than my MCMC.

Comment: I don't know enough about apple trees to give advice on this model, but I feel that the most important assumption is that every apple has a fixed probability of falling, independent of all other apples. If that feels fine, then the binomial model follows naturally. Instead of a truncated normal, you could also use (for instance) a Poisson distribution, although I don't have any theoretical justification beyond that it's a discrete non-negative distribution. How exactly did you fit your model? How can you compute the $\mathrm{Binomial}(N,p)$ for N a non-integer number?

Comment: @MauritsM You are right, and I see that this was wrong.  I have fixed the text to have `N = DiscreteUniform`, but the question remains.  I'm still afraid I'm over-estimating, and I am really uncertain to my chose of modeling the $q_i$.

Comment: Although you write you "end up with an estimate," I cannot find any description of *how* you make that estimate.  What is your method??  Running a simulation cannot succeed because the logic is circular: in order to simulate you need to supply estimates in the first place.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment.  I have tried to come up with estimates in several ways, but haven't found any that gives a value corresponding to the industry, that's why I ask _if my model seems right to you_.

Comment: ... the estimates come from the mean output from `pymc3`, I've tried to come up with quantile estimates (but both mean and median are often higher than I would like), and I've tried to fit a beta/beta-binomial on the resulting N values and tried to use the _expected value_ of the resulting beta distribution.

Comment: My question is really: *does the model seem correct* or can you think of any improvements?

Comment: **If** some apples fall down easier that others, then fewer of those will remain for the later kicks, so your assumption of a constant $p$ seems doubtful. You would need some field experiments, knowing the truth (by exhaustive counting) to check/better your model!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen If you search for removal sampling, the first result (I see) is a paper on removal sampling which defines the _necessary assumptions_ as follows: 1. Each individual in the population has an equal and independent chance of being captured. That is, the sampling must be random.
2. Except for the effects of the trapping, the population is not increasing or decreasing in size (through the combined effects of births, deaths, immigration, and emigration)
3. The probability of capturing an individual is the same for each period of sampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results look reasonable given your model and your other assumptions. I can't speak to whether the model (and the assumptions) are themselves reasonable.

I'm going to change the notation a bit because I like to use the "$p$" to denote a probability density (or mass) function. So I'll use $\theta$ as the probability of "success" instead.

The observations are given by
\begin{equation}
q_{1:K} = (q_1, \ldots, q_K) .
\end{equation}
The likelihood is
\begin{equation}
p(q_{1:K}|N,\theta) = p(q_1|N,k)\prod_{k=2}^K p(q_k|q_{1:k-1},N,\theta) ,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
p(q_1|N,\theta) &= \textsf{Binomial}(q_1|N,\theta) \\
p(q_k|q_{1:k-1},N,\theta) &= \textsf{Binomial}\left(q_k\Big|N - \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} q_j,\theta\right) .
\end{align}
The prior for the latent variables $N$ and $\theta$ is flat. Therefore, the posterior is proportional to the likelihood:
\begin{equation}
p(N,\theta|q_{1:K}) \propto p(q_{1:K}|N,\theta) . 
\end{equation}

We can apply the Metropolis-within-Gibbs sampler. Let $(\theta^{(r)},N^{(r)})$ denote the current state of the chain. The full-conditional posterior distribution for $\theta$ delivers the following:
\begin{equation}
\theta^{(r+1)} \sim p(\theta|q_{1:K},N^{(r)}) = \textsf{Beta}(\theta|a,b^{(r)}) 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
a &= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^K q_k \\
b^{(r)} &= 1 + K\,N^{(r)} - \sum_{k=1}^K (K-k+1)\,q_k .
\end{align}
To draw $N^{(r+1)}$ we can take a Metropolis step, using a symmetric uniform discrete proposal. Let $N' = N^{(r)} + \delta$ where $\delta \sim \textsf{Uniform}(-3,3)$ for example. Then
\begin{equation}
N^{(r+1)} = \begin{cases}
N' & M \ge u \\
N^{(r)} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} ,
\end{equation}
where $u \in \textsf{Uniform}(0,1)$ and
\begin{equation}
M = \frac{p(q_{1:K}|N',\theta^{(r+1)})}{p(q_{1:K}|N^{(r)},\theta^{(r+1)})} .
\end{equation}
Given the draws $\{(\theta^{(r)},N^{(r)})\}_{r=1}^R$ one can produce figures that are similar to those in the question (except that the distribution for $N$ should be discrete). The posterior mode for $N$ is 53 and the posterior mean is about 55. There's about a 10% chance that $N\ge 60$.

Comment: Notational quibble: should it not be $p(q_k | N, q_1, \ldots, q_{k-1}, \theta) \sim Binomial(.)$? The full likelihood being p(q_{1:k}|N,\theta), with $q_i$s not independent but can be factorized $p(q_1 | N, \theta)p(q_2 | N, q_1, \theta),$ etc.?

Comment: @einar Quite right. Thank you.